# Content is accessible in ServerSideProps for NextJS when using Next Auth.js

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm learning to use Next Auth and I'm following https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side.

I expected since `getServerSideProps()` runs on the server side only, that the `return` for unauthorized would only show "ACCESS GRANTED!!! ..." but I'm able to search the source code in the browser and find the hash secret I made.

I had some issues so I altered the example code; notably I included a `useState` for running on server only substituting the if `type === "undefined` method.

**pages/protected.js**

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Typography } from "@mui/material"
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next"

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions),
    },
  }
}

export default function Profile() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState<boolean>(false)

  // Run on server only
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])

  if (isClient && session) {
    return (
      <>
        <Typography>
          ACCESS GRANTED!!! SECRET: 11c6c096-f677-4432-b7ca-2d1216df73a3
        </Typography>
      </>
    )
  }
  return <Typography>NO ACCESS</Typography>
}
```

Is there something I'm not seeing or not understanding here?  I'm able to use the authentication properly and see my session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misunderstood the way `getServerSideProps()` works.

According to https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props, nowhere does it say that the "whole" page is serverside only.

I was confused by "Next.js will pre-render this page on each request" and interpreted this as the component (in this case `Profile()`) contents will re-render on each request.

But for sure the contents of the `getServerSideProps()` function will be serverside.